# No key binding on login

Tags: keyboard, lxde

I have a Raspberry Pi 3, running

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I use LXDE. However, on reboot and login, my keymap is not properly loaded. For example, window switching via Alt-Tab does not work. It only works after I execute

```
sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
```

or if i run raspi-config (which ends up executing udevadm)

*excerpt from raspi-config:*

```
do_configure_keyboard() {
  dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration &&
  printf "Reloading keymap. This may take a short while\n" &&
  invoke-rc.d keyboard-setup start || return $?
  udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
  return 0
```

}

but if i rlog out and back in, the keymap once again isn't loaded. I have tried 2 different USB keyboards and, in each case, they are plugged in during reboot. Since my keybindings are defined in my home directory (~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml), I assume that the keymap should be loaded on login (not boot), but I'm not really sure of how/when the keymap binding mechanism works.

I would like to have the keybindings working on login. I could always work around the issue by running udevadm in a login script (run as root), but somehow I think the system would be designed to work without having to explicitely do that. Any help would be appreciated.

*/etc/default/keyboard*

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBMODEL="pc104"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

*excerpt from ~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml*

```
<!-- Keybindings for window switching --> 
<keybind key="A-Tab">
  <action name="NextWindow"/>
</keybind>
```

Update:

I'm looking into the process for X->window manager->desktop (openbox/LXDE-pi) on login.

Looking at keyboard events to see what changes before/after

```
xev -event keyboard
```

upon login to LXDE environment. Pressing ALT, followed by TAB, releasing TAB, then ALT results in the following events:

```
KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x25d, subw 0x0, time 99404308, (315,-475), root:(495,320),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x25d, subw 0x0, time 99404744, (315,-475), root:(495,320),
    state 0x80, keycode 23 (keysym 0xff09, Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) " "
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) "   "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x25d, subw 0x0, time 99405115, (315,-475), root:(495,320),
    state 0x80, keycode 23 (keysym 0xff09, Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (09) " "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x25d, subw 0x0, time 99405158, (315,-475), root:(495,320),
    state 0x80, keycode 64 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

after executing
    sudo udevadm trigger --verbose --subsystem-match=input --action=change

the same key sequence creates the following events

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  93  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Unfortunately, I still don't understand why Keymap isn't translating the key events until after i reload the keymap with udevadm